# How can I save a variable for later use in a "While" loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a project for my Comp Sci class where I have to make an order form for a pizza restaurant. I am required to have the person select the size of the pizza, and the toppings wanted. I am trying to make a loop so that you can order multiple pizzas and multiple toppings per pizza. However, the way I currently have it, every time I re-run the loop to "order" another pizza, it resets the variables. Is there a way to do make it so I save the variable for later use when calculating the total price of the order? This project is in python, but we are technically using this site: https://www.jdoodle.com/python-programming-online/ because not everyone in the class is able to use the actual program since we are working online, and some people have chromebooks. It is mostly the same as the Python IDLE program, but requires you to type print more.

This is the main portion of the code:

```
while again == "y":
    size = input("Select Size (Small = $8, Medium = $10, Large = $12. Select a Number 1-3: ")
    print size
    if size == 1:
        pizzasize = 8
        pizzaname = "Small"
    if size == 2:
        pizzasize = 10
        pizzaname = "Medium"
    if size == 3:
        pizzasize = 12
        pizzaname = "Large"
    topprice = 0
    print
    again2 = "y"
    while again2 == "y":
        print ("Step 3: Select Toppings")
        print
        print ("Toppings: None, Extra Cheese, Pepperoni, Sausage, Bacon, Pineapple, Peppers")
        topping = input("Select a Number 1-7: ")
        print topping
        if topping == 1:
            topname = "None"
        if topping == 2:
            topname = "Extra Cheese"
        if topping == 3:
            topname = "Pepperoni"
        if topping == 4:
            topname = "Sausage"
        if topping == 5:
            topname = "Bacon"
        if topping == 6:
            topname = "Pineapple"
        if topping == 7:
            topname = "Peppers"
        print ("Would You Like Another Topping?")
        again2 = raw_input("Press Y/N: ")
        print again2
        print

        topprice += 1.25
        print topprice



    print ("Would You Like To Order Another?")
    again = raw_input("Press Y/N: ")
    print again
    if again == "y" and size ==1:
        pizzasize += 8
    if again == "y" and size ==2:
        pizzasize += 10
    if again == "y" and size ==3:
        pizzasize += 12
    print pizzasize
    print
```

Comment: FWIW, I'd pull out the "mapping" code into separate functions (eg. `topname = get_topping_name(topping)`). This will help simplify the actual loop code.

Comment: Anyway, to the primary question: use a `list`, store a new "pizza" object with properties or a simple `dict` of such (or have one list for ever pizza property..): `pizzas = list()`. Then, after adding to all the toppings use `pizzas.append(pizza)` (or appropriate variant) to add the information to the collection of pizzas. See https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists etc.

Comment: Try declaring the variables *outside* the `while` loop.

Comment: Let's back up a second...  Leo, in your class have you covered data containers such as `list` and `dictionary` ?  If not, this will be tough to do and perhaps the best you could do would be to print off the "current pizza" and then do the whole thing again.